# Gradle Build & Execution of Robotium project (Multi Module)

Tags: gradle, robotium

I'm trying to execute my Robotium tests in a multi-module project using Gradle, version 1.12. But it doesn't execute on my emulator and the test report shows no tests were run. On the command line I also don't see any error. It shows everything run successful.

Project Structure:

```
-wl-multi-test
    wl-multi-test-application
    wl-multi-test-robolectrictest
    wl-multi-test-robotiumtest
```

Global dependencies are

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    classpath 'org.robolectric.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.10.+'
}
```

The Robolectric tests run fine and I see the report.

Commands I tried:

- `gradle clean test`
- `gradle clean :wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:connectedAndroidTest`

Output I got:

```
:clean
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:clean
:wl-multi-test-robolectrictest:clean
:wl-multi-test-application:clean
:wl-multi-test-robolectrictest:clean UP-TO-DATE
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:clean UP-TO-DATE
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:preBuild
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:compileDebugNdk
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:preDebugBuild
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:checkDebugManifest
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:prepareDebugDependencies
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:compileDebugAidl
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:compileDebugRenderscript
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:generateDebugBuildConfig
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:mergeDebugAssets
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:generateDebugResources
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:mergeDebugResources
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:processDebugManifest
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:processDebugResources
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:generateDebugSources
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:compileDebugJava
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:preDexDebug
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:dexDebug
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:validateDebugSigning
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:packageDebug
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:assembleDebug
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:compileDebugTestNdk
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:preDebugTestBuild
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:prepareDebugTestDependencies
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:compileDebugTestAidl
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:processDebugTestManifest
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:compileDebugTestRenderscript
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:generateDebugTestBuildConfig
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:mergeDebugTestAssets
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:generateDebugTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:generateDebugTestResources
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:mergeDebugTestResources
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:processDebugTestResources
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:generateDebugTestSources
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:compileDebugTestJava
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:preDexDebugTest
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:dexDebugTest
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:processDebugTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:packageDebugTest
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:assembleDebugTest
:wl-multi-test-robotiumtest:connectedAndroidTest
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the connectedInstrumentTests command?

Comment: Yes i tried that but i got an error saying conntectedInstrumentsTests not found.